# Could not find a part of the path 'C:\destPath\FileName.ext' when copying directories

Tags: c#, io

So, I have some logic that looks like the following:

```
private static void CopyToDestDirectory(string destDirectory, string srcDirectory)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(destDirectory))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destDirectory);
    }
    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(srcDirectory))
    {
        var filename = Path.GetFileName(file);
        var destPath = Path.Combine(destDirectory, filename);
        File.Copy(file, destPath, true);
    }

    ...
}
```

Usually this works, but every once in a while it does not.  For the times it does not work, I have a log file which resembles the following:

```
2016-12-22 15:49:21,670 [11] ERROR:
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\destPath\FileName.ext'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.Copy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite)
   at Namespace.Class.CopyToDestDirectory(String destDirectory, String srcDirectory)
   at Namespace.Class.CallingMethod()
```

I have no idea why I'm getting an exception about the destination path.  It doesn't make sense to me because I make sure to recreate the destination directory before I do my copying.

---

This is what the calling method looks like.  It's notable in that it deletes the dest directory before calling `CopyToDestDirectory` I wouldn't expect this to be a problem because, and I just recreate the directory it again, and because both this and `CopyToDestDirectory` are synchronous, but I honestly am not familiar with all of the low-level details behind the System.IO functions, so I think it's worth mentioning.

```
public void CallingMethod()
{
    try
    {
        ...

        if (Directory.Exists(destDirectory))
        {
            Directory.Delete(destDirectory, true);
        }
        string srcDirectory = GetSrcDirectory();
        CopyToDestDirectory(destDirectory, srcDirectory);

        ...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _log.Error("", ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

What might cause an error like this?

Comment: Could be a timing/syncing issue

Comment: @TheLethalCoder  I can't think of any other processes that should be interfering with that part of the filesystem when the issue occurs.  Is that the kind of timing/syncing issue you're thinking of?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder It does delete the destination directory right before calling this method, but it should all be synchronous

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case with powershell before create SymLinks/Junctions to renewed content of a directory.

as workaround: I´ve ended up in writing a loop, delete/create directory while it exists/or not. I wanted to write a log, for loop case, but since the changes it worked at the first time. strange, maybe the mistake was in the code around, but I hadn´t reproduce it. maybe it´s enough to call Directory.Exists() a second time.